# invoke custom java class in WSO2 esb

Tags: wso2-esb

I need to invoke a custom java class using WSO2 esb. The class takes an input parameter as a string and returns the XmlObject from the method.

How to achieve this using WSO2 and which mediator to use for the same?

regards
Amit Pawar.

Comment: If you have solved how you did it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom class mediators to achieve this[1]. Within this mediator you have to call your method and then set the result to the message context as a property and obtain it down the line in the mediation flow.

[1] - `https://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB480/Class+Mediator`

Answer (score 0):

You can also refer the sample in [1] to have a clear idea

[1] https://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB480/Sample+380:+Writing+your+own+Custom+Mediation+in+Java